# PHP in command line

Tags: php, python, command-line, terminal, code-testing

Using Python I can test my code in the terminal / command line by typing

```
python 
python> print "hello world"
```

I would like to do this with PHP too, but when typing:

```
php
echo "hello world";
```

it does not work.. Is this possible? what should I do? 
A quick search on the internet gives a lot of results that call an actual .php file to run. I only want to test a single sentence if possible, without creating files and stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
php -a
```

which starts an [interactive PHP shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php). Be aware that this requires PHP to be built with **--with-readline** (which is not the case if you're using the bundeled PHP with Mac OS X e.g.).

Alternatively, if you don't require the interactivity of a separate shell, use

```
php -r 'print_r(get_defined_constants());'
```

to execute a PHP snippet (this doesn't require the readline support).

Answer (score 1):

```
php -r "echo 'hello world';"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `php` without the `-a` option, don't forget the `<?php` at the start