# how to compile php with the --with-readline option

Tags: php, windows, interactive-shell

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480814/is-there-a-simple-php-shell-for-windows/8480957) about a PHP interactive shell, similar to python's.  after viewing [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) it looks like what I need to do is compile PHP with the --with-readline option.  The problem is, on Windows, I don't know how to do that.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: May be helpful link for You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117447/php-in-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readline library is not available on Windows.

Comment: This is true, although there are some "workarounds" that might help you. See the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7.1, ext/readline is supported on Windows and is delivered with the official builds. See UPGRADING for details.

Thanks.